# Ext Js how to Group textfields by rows & columns?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I want to group textfields by columns & rows, I have tried with **layout type 'table'**  but I'm unable to group the textfields, I need Like below, please help me, Im completely new to Ext jS,thanks in advance.

```
              column 1           column 2              column 3

 Row 1     Name: textfield     RollNo: textfield     Language: textfield
 Row 2     Age:  textfield     Ph: textfield         Class: textfield        
 Row 3     ID:   textfield     Email: textfield      Class: textfield
```

Comment: Which ExtJS versions and framework type are you using? ExtJS 6.2 classic or what?

Comment: @pagep Im using ExtJs version-6.2 & classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is  multiple ways how to achieve this but what you could do is to set the [layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html) of the main form to [hbox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.layout.container.HBox.html) (horizontal box) than add 3 containers (or you could use [fieldset](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.FieldSet.html), [fieldcontainers](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.FieldContainer.html)) and in them set the layout to default or [vbox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.layout.container.VBox.html) (vertical). You can also play with the [flex](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-flex) config to position your fields correctly.

You can always add more containers and play with their layouts.

Also you could try to use table layout http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#layout-table

I personally use Sencha Architect so it's much faster for me to create such form with hbox and vbox layouts.

Check out this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/200h

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.myform',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
        'Ext.form.field.Text'
    ],

    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'My Form',

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            flex: 1,
            height: 120,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            flex: 1,
            height: 120,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            flex: 1,
            height: 120,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

});
```